# NSOutlineView - How to remove the expand/collapse toggle

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I have a NSOutlive view that I would like to remove the toggle from some rows. The Zones and Assets rows are group items (header rows) and should not be collapsable. The problem is that is I answer `NO` to `- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item` for these items, the toggles do go away, but then I can't programmatically expand then either.

Is there any way to remove the toggle from specific rows?

[image: Example]

Comment: Maybe this helps you, not sure if its the same problem: https://devforums.apple.com/message/643148#643148

Comment: @JustSid - write that up as an answer and I'll mark it correct. specifically `-outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently is by design and expected behavior (don't ask why, I have no idea). See also this thread in the developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/643148#643148

The problem seems to appear when you turn of the outline cells by returning `NO` in `outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:`.